# Unable to navigate if i keep the .xhtml files in sub folder(other than the root folder) in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf

I am new to JSF 2.0. I was practising the implementation of JSF 2.0. When i keep my A.xhtml file in the root folder and navigate to another B.xhtml file which is in subfolder in root folder, the page is navigating successfully. But when i am navigation from B.xhtml to any other file, it is showing page not found error. If i moved my B.xhtml file to the root folder , in this case i am able to navigate to another page.

Seems like it is with the problem of handling paths, when my .xhtml files are in sub folders other than directly in the root folder.

Please let me know where it is going wrong.

Your solution is greatly appreciated  !!

Thanks,
Sai.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I placed the sub folder in WEB-INF folder. Instead if i moved the subfolders to WebConent folder., it is working.